# How to create sub domain in asp .net step step through coding.?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**My domain is WWW.Bank.com which is configured to Bank folder.**

1. I want to access same folder by demo.Bank.com/user.Bank.com/anything.Bank.com i.e I don't want to create new sub folder in my root.
2. If I give URL like demo.Bank.com then internal pages should be demo.Bank.com/folder 1/home.asp x likewise..
   Please help. If anyone have any dummy code then please share.

Answer (score 0):

This goes beyond ASP.NET in the core of the DNS.

You need to have control of the DNS zone of your 'bank.com' domain. If your DNS provider has a web-service for adding, deleting and updating DNS A and CNAME records, you could do that, but that's very unusual thing to do. Then again, you need to bind each domain name in the IIS website if you do not have a dedicated IP for such purposes.

Blogging websites are a good example for this, they usually host blogs on blogname.blogsite.com, such as alice.blogsite.com or bob.blogsite.com and as they usually have huge amount of different blogs, they resort to a single DNS record to take care of all of them.

That's called [wildcard DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) and is what you need. Add one DNS record called *.yourdomain.com and point it to a **dedicated IP address**. That will work for any subdomain name combination, even the ones you don't want and where no content will exist (you're still going to be able to handle 404's). Then, on the server, add that IP address as a secondary network address. In the IIS bind your website to that IP address without Host Header (domain name) constraint, so it would receive all requests for that IP, regardless of domain name.

Finally, in your ASP.net code fetch `Request.Url.Host` and you're going to get your subdomain as it was typed by the user.

(You can also go with a single IP address, but then no other websites must exist on the server.)